# How do you use a while loop to check if index is in range of a list for removing items from a shopping cart?

Tags: python

I am trying to use a while loop to keep asking which item to remove from a list until the user enters an existing index in python. Basically when the user is asked, "What item would you like to remove?" the user should be able to enter a number starting from 1 instead of zero, and up to whatever number of items, there are. For example, if there are ten items, the user should be able to enter 1 -10, not 0 - 9. I have already converted the user input to a zero-based index. Now I need to be able to keep asking "What item would you like to remove?" until the user inputs an existing index.

Here is the code that I am getting stuck on:

```
items = []

prices = []

quantities = []

item = input("\nWhat item would you like to remove? ").strip()

while item != range(0, len(items)):
    print("\nSorry, that is not a valid number.")
    item = input("\nWhat item would you like to remove? ").strip()
    item_remove = items[int(item) - 1]

    items.pop(int(item) - 1)
    prices.pop(int(item) - 1)
    quantities.pop(int(item) - 1)

    print(item_remove  + " removed.")
    break
```

I shortened the code so you wouldn't have to read as much, but here is what is happening. When I put in an existing index it displays the print statement "Sorry, that is not a valid number." and then asks for the input "What item would you like to remove?" a second time then after you enter an existing index again it removes the item and goes back to the main menu option that I am using in my code. However, if you enter an index that does not exist, it displays the print statement "Sorry, that is not a valid number." then asks "What item would you like to remove?", but the second time that I enter an index that does not exist the code crashes saying ***list index out of range***. Is there any way that I could get this code to keep asking "What item would you like to remove?" followed by the print statement "Sorry, that is not a valid number." until I enter an existing index? If you need more code let me know, and I greatly appreciate any help or feedback.